flutter : App rejected by google play console due to login error. In mobile login working fine
This is my code for login method
`[enter image description here][1]
void loginUser() async{
var reqestBody = {
  "registration": cardNumberController.text,
  "password" : passwordCOntroller.text
};
final connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if(connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.wifi && connectivityResult !=     ConnectivityResult.mobile){
    QuickAlert.show(
      context: context,
      type: QuickAlertType.info,
      title: 'Oops...',
      text: 'No Connection',
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      titleColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    );
    return;
}

loadingController.isLoading.value = true;

try {
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(EndPoint.loginUrl),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: jsonEncode(reqestBody)
  ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 60));
  var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);

  if (jsonResponse['status'] == 200) {
    String accessToken = jsonResponse['TOKEN_MEMBER'];
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('access_token', accessToken);
    loadingController.isLoading.value = false;
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return MainContent();
      }),
          (r) {
        return false;
      },
    );
  } else {
    print(jsonResponse['message']);
    QuickAlert.show(
      context: context,
      type: QuickAlertType.warning,
      title: 'Oops...',
      text: jsonResponse['message'],
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      titleColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    );
    print(jsonResponse['status']);
    loadingController.isLoading.value = false;
  }
} catch (e) {
  // Handle exceptions here
  print('Error: $e');
  QuickAlert.show(
    context: context,
    type: QuickAlertType.error,
    title: 'Error',
    text: e.toString(),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    titleColor: Colors.red,
    textColor: Colors.red,
  );
  loadingController.isLoading.value = false;
}

}`

In my mobile phone in debug mode this is working file. I have tested with vpn also working file. I have test with 2G network still working.Is there any another library to use for api call for login.
But google play console reject me due to login issue.
I want to deploy google play store as early as possible.

did you generate the dummy number for testing? you must should provide one, so and set the otp so they can test it, you must provide the dummy account and password so they can test it
